# Modify filtered data grid when a row is selected

Tags: acumatica

I have a processing page which may contain multiple rows with a common id value.  When a row is selected, I would like to deselect and disable all other rows with the same id value.  Likewise if that row is deselected I want to re-enable all the other rows with the same id.  I know I need to use a rowupdated event but I don't know how to attach to the cache for the grid.  Any help is appreciated.

```
    public void EDIOrder_RowUpdated(PXCache sender, PXRowUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        EDIOrder row = (EDIOrder)e.Row;
        if (row != null)
        {
            // attach to cache and update other rows with same id
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar situation, where PayoutDetail records belonging to the same Payout needed to stay in synch.  I chose Field_Updated for the event handling to select or deselect like-records:

```
    protected virtual void RCPayoutDetail_Selected_FieldUpdated(
            PX.Data.PXCache cache, PX.Data.PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        RCPayoutDetail row = (RCPayoutDetail)e.Row;

        if (row != null)
        {
             // keep all Payouts in synch
            foreach (RCPayoutDetail rec in this.Records.Select())
            {
                if (rec.RCPayoutID == row.RCPayoutID &&
                        row.RCPayoutDetailID != rec.RCPayoutDetailID)
                {
                    cache.SetValue<RCPayoutDetail.selected>(rec, row.Selected);
                }
            }

           this.Records.View.RequestRefresh();
        }
    }
```

In your case for enable/disable, try adding:

```
PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<RCPayoutDetail.selected>(
    cache, rec, !(bool)row.Selected);

// optional, see RowSelected comments and changes suggested below 
cache.SetStatus(rec, row.Selected == true ? 
    PXEntryStatus.Notchanged : PXEntryStatus.Modified);
```

In a processing page, if you are disabling the entire row, but only enabling the Selected field during RowSelected, then add the following "if" line to RowSelected for interplay with row's Status:

```
    protected virtual void RCPayoutDetail_RowSelected(PX.Data.PXCache cache, PX.Data.PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        RCPayoutDetail row = (RCPayoutDetail)e.Row;

        if (row != null)
        {
            //Set Row Enabled = false
            PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled(cache, e.Row, false);

            // optional if line, otherwise always enable Selected
            if(cache.GetStatus(row) == PXEntryStatus.Updated || row.Selected == null)        
            PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<RCPayoutDetail.selected>(
                  cache, row, true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the details!  In the first code block I assume RoyRecords is the class for the filtered data grid, correct?  That was the piece I wasn't sure of - how to attach to the cache for the grid.  Do I need to use RequestRefresh to update the screen after changing the cache?

Comment: I found RequestRefresh helpful, yes.  I edited the code block, Records is the View for the filtered data grid.